# Is $P(1)$ true?

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

I just recently found out this fake proof by induction that all positive integers are equal from *The Mathematical Gazette*:

Let $P(n)$ be the propositition:

"If the maximum of two positive integers is $n$ then the integers are equal."

**Clearly $P(1)$ is true.** Assuming that $P(n)$ is true, assume that $u$ and $v$ are positive integers such that the maximum of $u$ and $v$ is $n + 1$. Then the maximum of $u - 1$ and $v - 1$ is $n$, forcing $u - 1 = v - 1$ by the validity of $P(n)$. Therefore, $u = v$.

I see this, almost a duplicate: [Find the fallacy in the following treatment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190544/find-the-fallacy-in-the-following-treatment), and I understand it, but I got into an argument with someone. They say that the base case $P(1)$ is in fact, *not* true, because, either the two integers are already the same, or they are different, and only case where $P(1)$ is true is where they must be already the same, in which case we haven't proved anything.

I say, that the special case $n = 1$ *forces* the numbers to be the same, which makes $P(1)$ true.

Who is correct?

Comment: Yes, but $P(2)$ is false.  Work through the argument to see where it fails for $n=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base case is correct. The fallacy is in the induction step when you assume that $u-1$ and $v-1$ are positive integers.

Comment: Why aren't they correct?

Comment: @1613585 When you try to prove $P(2)$ as suggested by lulu, you may take $u=1$ and $v=2$ in which case $u-1=0$ and $v-1=1$ where the base case will not apply.

Comment: They say that, yes, the base case *is* correct, *but only* if you add a restriction that the positive integers are the same, which proves nothing. (What I mean by "they" is the person that argued with me).

Comment: @1613585 That restriction is not necessary. If there are two positive integers with maximum $1$, then they must both be equal to $1$.

Comment: I talked with him again, and he keeps saying that if they are both equal to $1$, then there's no point, as you assume the statement you want to prove.

Comment: @1613585 Well you can't convince everybody. I do think that in some sense all provable results are empty of meaning, because they're already just consequences of the axioms.